# Derived class constructor taking base class as argument (Is it Good practice?)

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have a two simple classes below, one base and another deriving from it. 
In the derived class there are two constructor, one which takes all arguments needed for base and derived, and another which takes a Base class reference itself as argument.

I know the constructor which takes the base class reference as argument is not a good practice. 
However, I was wondering why is it not considered a good practice?
It achieves the same thing as the other constructor. 
Could someone please clarify why is it not a good OOP practice?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int a, int b):
        m_a(a),
        m_b(b)
    {}

    Base(const Base& b):
        m_a(b.m_a),
        m_b(b.m_b)
    {}

    ~Base() {}

protected:
    int m_a;
    int m_b;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // Constructor which takes base class argument and initializes base
    Derived(Base &base, int c):
        Base(base),
        m_c(c)
    {}


    Derived(int a, int b, int c):
        Base(a, b),
        m_c(c)
    {}

    ~Derived() {}

private:
    int m_c;
};

int main()
{
    Base base(1,2);
    Derived derived1(base, 3); //
    Derived derived2(1,2, 3);
}
```

Comment: where did you found that this is not a good practice?

Comment: I think it depends mostly on your design. If ``Derived`` is extension of the ``Base`` or a wrapper, then why not! But I guess it can cause some troubles in implementation, mostly if you use pointers and not copy everything everytime (just need to be careful and know implementation of ``Base``). I think it's not so good practice if you can think of ``Derived`` as something independent from ``Base`` or you want to hide implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be necessary to know the context in which you specify the first Derived constructor.

However, maybe it would be more elegant to define it with the `const Base` parameter. Something like:

```
Derived(const Base &base, int c):
        Base(base),
        m_c(c)
    {}
```

Thus, it tells the compiler that protects the state of `base` object.

Also, if you are using c ++ - 11, then you might be interested in declaring:

```
using Base::Base;
```

inside the `Derived` class, what makes that `Derived` inherits the constructors of `Base`.  Thus, you could add in your `main()`:

```
Derived derived3(1,2);
```

and that would compile perfectly.

In c++-11 you could you also could set a default value for `m_c` data member. for example

```
int m_c = 0;
```

And so the constructor inherited from `Base` would leave `Derived` in a consistent state

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that is not what I was looking for. Almost, all the C++ tutorials or books specify the derived taking all the base arguments and initializing the base members, I was wondering why should/shouldn't the derived class take the Base as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you show is *not* bad OOP practice. Users of `Derived` know about, and have access to, `Base` by virtue of the fact that `Derived` uses public inheritance. Because of this, you are not adding any dependencies and so are not making anything more restrictive or complex.

That said, even if `Derived` was using protected or private inheritance, it might not necessarily be bad practice depending on whether users of `Derived` would otherwise know about class `Base`.

Imagine this:

```
class Derived { // no inheritance
public:
    void doSomething(const X& b); // `X` could be `Base`, `Foo`, or `std::string` for that matter...
};
```

Would you call the above bad practice? I think not. The key here, as in the code you presented (assuming you added the const qualifier to the Base& as lrleon suggested,) is that you are using `Base` as a value type. `Derived` is not holding a pointer/reference to the base object being passed in, so what you have is normal parameter passing, and there is nothing unusual or bad practice about parameter passing.

Comment: Now one could argue that it isn't *efficient* code, because of the extra copy, but that's a different question.